# PDP page and Add to cart issue in spartacus storefront

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have done the setup with spartacus and the storefront is up and running. If I am trying to redirect to PDP page it is not loading correctly.

[image]

If I am trying to add the product to cart the popup is loading continuously like below.

[image]

Anyone faced this issue, please help me out.

Comment: Please provide more details like spartacus version and logs from devtools console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like 2 separate issues:

1. The issue with PDP tabs should be resolved by using the latest version of the `spartacussampledataaddon` (`spartacussampledata`). See https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/3240
2. The issue with "Add to cart modal" requires troubleshooting.